# Why does "mash me a fin" mean loan me/give me five dollars?

Tags: etymology, slang

I've heard mash me a fin used before and understood it to mean "loan me five dollars"; however, I don't understand why mash me a fin means loan me five dollars. The only example I could find of it was here in the Jive Dictionary: http://www.cabcalloway.cc/jive_dictionary.htm.

Does anyone know why mash me a fin means loan me five dollars?

Comment: This seems like an obvious slang expression—you can’t always expect those to make sense or stand up to much scrutiny.

Comment: I've only heard the expression used to describe high-fives, which makes sense b/c slapping hands and mashing fins are relatively similar actions. Perhaps there is some connection between "Give me five" as in a high-five and "mash me a fin" as in give me five dollars?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as General Reference because "fin" is just slang for a five-dollar bill. Thus "mash me a fin" is pretty obvious. [Etymonline states](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fin) that in the US "fin" is attested from 1925 and in the UK it's attested since the 1860s.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 what if there's an actual time and place where somebody remarkable just popped this out into the word? Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fin is a sailor term for hand:

> **FINUF**, a five-pound note. **Double FINUF**, a ten-pound note. — German, fung, five -The slang dictionary; . [Hotten, John Camden],
>   1832-1873. [from old catalog]

Comment: I assume you mean *fünf*, not *fung*?

Comment: @ErikKowal In another edition of The slang dictionary; . [Hotten, John Camden], 1832-1873. it is clearly 'funf' but the edition I quoted from (original text , not OCR) appears to be the letter 'g' -perhaps a typo

Comment: As I already posted in a comment on the answer, "fin" is a slang term for $5. That seems like a much more likely matching definition for the OP's question, no?

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇, congrats -I gave you a a +